# How do I create a looping function with this using php?

Tags: php, function, loops

I'm trying to create what I think are a series of functions that will loop through some code and yield a color. Color result will be base on time range and totals.

Unfortunately, because my skillset in PHP is very low, I have only managed to get to where I'm at by starting off writing out what I wanted, then transition what I wanted into what I think would be the start of the code. This was based on what I understood from the Academy of Code website and a Udemy Course. The end result is for a website. If I could get help on what is below, I'm pretty sure I can take it from there.

```
If tot_time == 48 mths

If (exp_date >= 0 mths && < 13 mths) && (cred_end == cred_start)
    {
//Make background color red
bkgrd == red;
}

If (exp_date >= 12 mths && < 25 mths) && (cred_end == cred_start)
   {
//Make background color red
bkgrd == red;
}

If (exp_date >= 24 mths && < 37 mths) && (cred_end == cred_start)
   {
//Make background color red
bkgrd == red;
}

If (exp_date >= 36 mths) && (cred_end == cred_start)
   {
//Make background color white
bkgrd == white;
}

If (exp_date >= 0 mths && < 13 mths) && (cred_end == cred_start) / 4
    {
//Make background color red
bkgrd == red;
}

If (exp_date >= 12 mths && < 25 mths) && (cred_end == cred_start) / 4
    {
//Make background color red
bkgrd == red;
}
```

The expected result is that the date range and completion of the math will yield a color.

Comment: You could just set the default `$bkgrd = 'red';` and then run your check for the white background. It would be far less code. Try writing the actual code and if you get stuck post your code and problem.

Comment: Thank you Second2None for your response. I was actually thinking about the background starting off as white, and if the conditions are met, it would change to either red, yellow, or some other color based on the conditions met. I would think that falls in line with what you are saying though, so definitely thank you for your response. It might take me a day or so to get the updated code, as I am completely new at this level of coding.